# Not finding .Include() method in my EF implementing Generic repository

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using Generic repository to wrap DbContext and DbSet classes from upper level.
However, when in certain queries I need to use ".Include()" method to include navigation properties. But I am unable to find these methods on repository methods returing IQueryable

Like,

```
this.repository.GetQuery<GeneralCalendarDates>()
```

this doesn't have include method, though I can use .ToList() here.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Include` for `IQueryable<T>` is an extension method that is implemented in namespace `System.Data.Entity` in the assembly `EntityFramework.dll`. So your project must reference this assembly and you must add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

at the beginning of your code file. It will make the string and lambda based version of `Include` available, so that you can use:

```
orderQuery.Include("Customer")
```

or

```
orderQuery.Include(o => o.Customer)
```

Comment: or using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; if .NET Core

Answer (score 1):

I'm using EF6 and dotnet6 and imported like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Then I was able to use `Include()` in the code:

```
var parent = _context.Parent
                    .Include(o => o.Children)
                    .ToList();
```