# EF Core no .Include() method on DBset

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently completely unable to call .Include() and intellisense (in vscode) doesn't seem to think it exists.

Now after a long time searching the web I've found this:

[Not finding .Include() method in my EF implementing Generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175702/not-finding-include-method-in-my-ef-implementing-generic-repository)

which seems to suggest that .Include exists only in System.Data.Entities, which is only available for EF 5 and 6.

So how do i eager load my list property for an entity in EF core?

heres my context

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    //Set new datasources like this: public DbSet<class> name { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Domain.Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Domain.ResourceType> ResourceTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./something.db");
    }
}
```

Heres the data classes:

```
public class Resource
{
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ResourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public ResourceType ResourceType { get; set; }
}
public class ResourceType
{
    public int ResourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

Then I do something like:

```
public List<ResourceType> GetAll()
{
    var router = new Database();

    var result = router.ResourceTypes.Include(rt => rt.Resources); //It's here there's absolutely no .Include method

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Does .Include not exist in EF Core?

Comment: Did you hit `Ctrl+.` on the error message, so Visual Studio 2015/2017 can suggest you using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace? ;)

Comment: I'm using visual studio code on Ubuntu

Comment: Just add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` & write above code. Even if intellisense cannot find it, it should compile properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core does not contain a definition for 'Include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107228/entity-framework-core-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-include)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It's a direct consequence of a missing reference in the file where I'm making a call to the method (though i'm not quite sure i understand how...)

Anyways, adding:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

like [Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455493/tseng) and [Smit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484219/smit) suggested, did the trick. (in the file in which i define the function)

Though why that works i have no idea. I thought `.include` would automatically be available through the `DbSet`.

Thanks though! :)

Small, late EDIT: as [Christian Johansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100688/christian-johansen) pointed out in his comment, the reason it needs the import to see the method signature, is that it is an extension method, which is a topic I strongly encourage any up-and-coming C# developer to learn about as it is immensely useful.

Comment: Its implemented as an extention method, so its not visible until you include the namespace where the extention method is implemented

Answer (score 11):

If you end up here, a user of EF 6 or below and happen to miss that OP actually mentioned this like I did, you want to add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

to your class.

Comment: Why didn't VS suggest that to me (like other LINQ methods), it is very unintuitive to guess you miss that using.

Comment: Great question @GeorgiG, haven't dug into it in a while but I might because that has always bugged me.

Comment: @GeorgiG - a year later I happened back past this question and started digging a bit.  Not sure why it didn't occur to me last year when you asked this and I responded, just not thinking I guess.  Anyway, because it's an extension method it won't show until you add the namespace it hails from.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634229/dbset-include-operator-for-ef7-accepting-string-path) is a previous answer that is tracking this issue in EF7.  It appears it is now 'included'.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not looking for the overload of .Include that enables .Include(string) but the .Include(t => t.property). And by All accounts that was available already back in 2015, so why can't I access it at all I wonder :(

Comment: Its [there](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs). Starts on line 2162. The intellisense for VSCode can be more problematic than regular visual studio. I would start by checking that you have all the necessary extensions installed.

Comment: Hm. I'll try calling it then. EF core version 1.0 and beyond should be fine, right. I have to wonder what's with the intellisense though, as the only problem I've had with it so far is when I rename a class... And even then it's just a program restart away.

Comment: Try using it and see if your project compiles and runs.