# How to get all movies of a director and display them in razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

(I am sorry I even can't explain my question properly.)

This is one of my first ***ASP Net Core*** projects. I want my web application to display individual pages for each Director and get a list of his/her movies to display there. Something like this:

[Screenshot of a movie website named letterboxd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDBLM.jpg)

(No need for poster, Just movie titles is fine)

---

I created two classes. One named **Movie**:

[Screenshot of Movie class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaokq.jpg)

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieId { get; private set; }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

And another class named **Director**:

[Screenshot of Director class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVEbB.jpg)

```
public class Director
{
    public int DirectorId { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then, I used the scaffolding tool and let Visual Studio to create DB context and the Razor pages automatically:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rgGa.jpg)

But, When I run the application I see the movie ***List*** property is not even included in the razor pages:

[Screenshot of list of Directors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sreuQ.jpg)

[Screenshot of a Directors' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O75ZG.jpg)

---

So, My goal is to display an individual page for each director that include the list of movies directed by him/her in the director's page.

But I know It's too much to ask all the problems in one question. Just show me the ways. Which approaches can I adopt? Which keywords should I use to search about it?!

If you kindly give me some ideas, I will try to study/search and try it out myself.

Comment: It seems that you aren't including the related data. Take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135149/ef-core-no-include-method-on-dbset

Comment: @GabrielHeming Thanks a lot. I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relationships are not loaded automatically; you must choose a loading strategy: eager, explicit, or lazy. Eager loading is by far the preferred approach, as it allows EF to issue a SQL join in the same initial query, instead of having to make additional queries later. To do that, you need only use `Include` when doing your query:

```
var directors = await _context.Directors.Include(x => x.Movies).ToListAsync();
```